# Text turns into squares in BGE, text not visible

Tags: game-engine

A sample file with dynamic text was created, and works fine. The same information was added to this working file, but when "P" is pressed, the text turns into a colored square. Here's a before and after pressing "P":
[image: Before "P"]

[image: After "P"]

The next pic shows debug information confirming the text is being changed:
[image: Text change confirmed]

In fact, this is the same with ALL the text in this file, static or dynamic. Obviously, I'm missing a setting somewhere. Any ideas would be appreciated.

I found this information on [Recording number of checkpoints passed](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/38017/recording-number-of-checkpoints-passed/38026#38026):

We first need to **change the font, because the default font will not display in the game engine.** (an answer by X-27)
I'm doing research on that now.

Here's a screenshot of the AlarmBox with logic bricks.

[image: AlarmBox with logic bricks]

[image]

Comment: I've changed to several different fonts. The same problem exists.

Comment: Would you try to alt + c to convert to mesh? If that doesn't work, try to give it a positive depth, which can be very small if you need it to be, and then convert.

Comment: @SilverRain: Converting to a mesh wouldn't work in this instance, it needs to be dynamic so when the low- and hi-angle alarms are being set, the numbers will change. Having said that, there are other places I could use that information. Also all the text has been extruded a bit to give it some height. Thanks for your thought!

Comment: What do you say you upload the blend to https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ and I see if I can recreate the error on my end?

Comment: @SilverRain: 37.1mb size...still want it?

Comment: @SilverRain: How about a few .png's relating to the parts of the program that are affected?

Comment: Well, like I said, to test it I would need the full blend. If it’s that big though, you might not want to upload it for fear someone might take it, if the website even lets you. But yes, if you upload it 37.1 MB is nothing. If you feel uncomfortable sharing, I reccomend you do not, just try it on newer computers.

Comment: Oh, did you do the usual, use a computer made in the last three years, updated graphics cards, windows 7/10, suitable RAM, etc.?

Comment: @SilverRain: Asrock 4-core, refurbished in March 2017, NVIDIA Graphics GP107 GeForce GTX 1050 Ti, 16GB Ram, AntiX-Linux 17 with all the updates. I sure hope that would be enough! Also, not afraid to share, but there's a 30MB limit to upload files. This file is an almost completed 25 ton P&H Omega Rough Terrain Crane. The boom doesn't have any text involved, I'll remove the boom and ship the rest your way.

Comment: Aha Linux. AFAIK, any professional will use Windows 7/10, macOS or at least Ubuntu. What do you say you try running the game on Windows 7/10 and see if you still have a problem. It might not be the answer you were looking for, but I think it is very likely.

Comment: @SilverRain: I'll remove the alarm box in the program before I revert to THAT inferior platform! I could rant on that, but I'll be nice...Thanks for your time.

Comment: @SilverRain: Actually, as I said previously, the example file I made (in AntiX-Linux 17) works flawlessly. There's something in my crane program that I did incorrectly. With enough time and effort, I'll stumble across it eventually.

Comment: UPDATE: I made another alarm box in a new file, (tested, works fine), put it in a library. Got rid of the alarm box that doesn't work in the crane. Appended the alarm box from the library, the crane turned black, as if I turned off the lighting, I press "P" and the crane shows normally, lighted, but the same happens with  numbers in the alarm box as in the first alarm box...a colored block, no numbers. I've repeated the remove and append procedure several times with same result. The crane stays black after the appended alarm box is removed, and when I reload the crane file, Blender crashes.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the background object is covering the text.

You need some distance between the text and it's background.

Comment: In wireframe mode, I turned the image 90 degrees after I put the text in place to ensure the text was extended above the background.The text is well above the background. Just now, I even increased the distance between the two with the same result. Thanks for your input.